# How to open downloaded file location in Slack?

Tags: windows, slack

Colleague sent me a file and I need to place that file to a particular location. After downloading the file, I clicked on "View all downloads" in the notification.

[image]

But the view that popped up does not allow me to view the files in folder:

[image]

Now given that it's a XML file, I can probably just open it and re-save it, but what do I do if I receive a binary file? Or an image that must not be altered by adding artifacts?

Answer (score 3):

Here https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/1265642810226675713 they said you can press-n-hold 'Shift' key to access 'open containing folder' option. But it works only in notification popup (your 1st screen) and doesnt work in 'Downloads' window. 
  Maybe there is some way how to do this in 'Downloads' window, but it seems we must search tweets for that ((